# Dúvida com helpers do mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho esse include em minha view(cshtml)

```
@model List<SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV>
```

Agora necessito criar uma tabela, e em uma TD eu coloco o label e em outra o TextBox. Fiz assim:

```
<tr>
 <td>@Html.Label("Razão Social")</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.)</td>//Aqui não consigo pegar a RazaoSocial
</tr>
```

Tentei Model => Model.... e também não veio nada, mudei para model => model... e nada também.

O que eu preciso realmente é criar um id para o textbox, porque trabalho com valores dinâmicos vindo de uma função jquery.

No Intellisense eu trago: Select<>, RemoveAt,Add, AddRange, Agregate<>, All<>, Any<> e etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria algo como:

```razor
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label(r => r[0].RazaoSocial)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r[0].RazaoSocial)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Para montar uma sequência dos campos, seria algo como:

```razor
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    @for (var i=0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label(r => r[i].RazaoSocial)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r[i].RazaoSocial)</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Não tinha visto que era um list.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que assim funciona:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
  <tr>
      <td>@Html.Label("Razão Social")</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBox(Model.RazaoSocial)</td>
  </tr>
}
```